# What's the best approach to this type of layout?

Tags: layout, html, css

I know I can just use margins and padding to accomplish what I want. But, that seems a little... I dunno, strange I guess. I just feel that there is a more... structured? way of doing this?

Here's what I want to do:
[image: Headings and lists inside a black DIV.]

How would you suggest I go about doing this? Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, there is a css grid system I am in love with, it is SO easy to implement and understand.  Check it out, its called the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/). Although it is made for 960px it is pretty easy to change.

```
<div class='container_4'><!-- this will be a container that takes up four grid spots-->
    <div class='grid_1 alpha'><!-- this will start from the first column in the container and will take one spot-->
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <li>List Item</li><!-- et cetera -->
    </div>
    <div class='grid_1'><!-- this takes up next spot and extends one col -->
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <li>List Item</li><!-- et cetera -->
    </div>
    <div class='grid_1'><!-- this takes up next spot and extends one col -->
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <li>List Item</li><!-- et cetera -->
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <li>List Item</li><!-- et cetera -->
    </div>
    <div class='grid_1 omega'><!-- this takes up last spot and extends one col -->
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <li>List Item</li><!-- et cetera -->
    </div>
</div> <!-- end the container -->
```

The alpha and omega classes go on the first and last grid items in a row.

Comment: I always use 960px. Thanks for your answer but I've always had a hard time trying to understand the grid system. Something about it.. just doesn't sink in.

Comment: Thank you Sydenam, sorry to be a pain.

Comment: OooOow - now I kind of get it, that is pretty wicked... Thanks @Sydenam! :)